# OpenAI and Javascript error : Getting 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') at Object.<anonymous>"

Tags: javascript, typeerror, openai-api, gpt-3

I am sorry for basic question but getting no where with what seems to be a very basic piece of code. I have npm installed latest version of openai. I am getting a constant error in my terminal:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/michalchojnacki/Desktop/Coding/OpenAi2/code.js:9:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Code:

```
const openai = require('openai');

openai.apiKey = "my API here";

const prompt = "What is the capital of France?";

const model = "davinci";

openai.completions.create({
  engine: model,
  prompt: prompt,
  max_tokens: 2048,
  n: 1,
  stop: '.',
  temperature: 0.5,
}, (error, response) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(response.choices[0].text);
  }
});
```

Would be grateful for any help!

I was expecting the terminal to give me the response to the prompt

Comment: Your code doesn't look anything like the [example in the README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai), did you try that?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the docs in the library it looks like you want something like this instead:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
});

async function getAiResponse(topic) {
  const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
  const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: "text-davinci-003",
    prompt: topic,
    max_tokens: 1024,
    n: 1,
    stop: null,
    temperature: 0.7
  });
  console.log(completion.data.choices[0].text);
}
getAiResponse("Your Prompt here");
```