# OpenAI API error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'choices')"

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-input, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I looked into various possible solutions:

- [OpenAI and Javascript error : Getting 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') at Object.<anonymous>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74969653/openai-and-javascript-error-getting-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-unde)
- https://github.com/davila7/code-gpt-docs/issues/57
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai

Here is my code:

```
import { config } from "dotenv"
config()

// New
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import readline from "readline"

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: 'My Key', // defaults to process.env["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
});

const userInterface = new readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout

})

userInterface.prompt()
userInterface.on("line", async input => {
    const res = await openai.chat.completions.create({
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        messages: [{ role: 'user', content: input}],
    })
    console.log(res.data.choices[0].message.content)
    userInterface.prompt()
})
```

When I run the code, I get the error message from the title of the post: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'choices')`.

I tried the following to fix the issue:

- Reload the Window with command: `Developer:Reload.Window`
- Using different OpenAI API keys
- Update `package.json` OpenAI to the latest version which is `4.11.1`
- Generally a different console.log code/output & code structure to solve the issue

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Everything works, besides the user input. As a guideline I used this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qNwoAAfnk4. I updated the project as far as I could. Why does the user input not work?

Also, the code on my PC has a functioning `apiKey` implemented. Thanks for reading!

Comment: can u log the res and see what u get

Comment: The error means that `res.data` is `undefined`, if that's not clear. Have you logged (or checked in the debugger) what `res` is after `await` expression?

Comment: I tested more up to date versions of res.data, many people seem to have the problem as stated in :"https://github.com/davila7/code-gpt-docs/issues/57", I don't know if it ultimately has been resolved. 


That it's possibly undefined is clear to me, as they update the documentation frequently, I don't know what you guys mean with res as well as logging the res. I am completely new to this. I can post the screenshot of the full error. I never worked with JavaScript/Node.JS this is my first project.

Comment: `console.log(res)` in other words.

Comment: I get the following:

> Hello
{
  id: 'chatcmpl-86hGKsEYEqm2H7jzkMPjo32bixACh',
  object: 'chat.completion',
  created: 1696606960,
  model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo-0613',
  choices: [ { index: 0, message: [Object], finish_reason: 'stop' } ],
  usage: { prompt_tokens: 8, completion_tokens: 9, total_tokens: 17 }
}
>

I wrote Hello as a prompt.

Comment: res shold come from const res = await.... as far I see the connection correctly.

Comment: `res.choices[0].message`?

Comment: Yea there's clearly not a `data` property.

Comment: glad to hear u got it working. btw i didnt downvote. maybe u can also write an answer

Comment: I did, hopefully it saves someone hours/minutes of searching the web. Thanks again for helping out!

Answer (score 4):

OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on August 16, 2023, and is a complete rewrite of the SDK. Among other things, there are changes in extracting the message content. See the `v3` to `v4` [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217).

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const chatCompletion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
  model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
  messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Hello!' }],
});

console.log(chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message);
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
  model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
  messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Hello!'}],
});

console.log(chatCompletion.choices[0].message); // There's no "data" property
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `console.log(res.data.choices[0].message.content)` to `console.log(res.choices[0])` or `console.log(res.choices[0].message.content)` solved the issue and fixed the proper user input feature.